# How can I hook into the UI rendering "engine" of ASP.NET Dynamic Data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic-data

I have decorated my model using Metadata classes attached to my model classes via the MetadataType attribute. I have some use the Range attribute, Required attribute, etc. *and some custom attributes I have created.*

Now I want to hook into the rendering engine (or whatever it is called) of the Dynamic Data framework and be able to change the way the UI is rendered based on *my custom attributes* as well as the standard System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations attributes.

Also, I might want to use ASP.NET MVC, so keep that in mind.

How do I do that? Pointing me to links would be great if you don't want to be verbose about explaining the nitty-gritty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a dynamic data project for ASP.NET MVC, but I think it is pretty much on hold:

http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=15459

I looked at it a while back and it partly worked, but I don't think it works with the latest bits.  I think eventually they are going to pull everything together, but it will be some time.  What I do right now is I have some helper classes that read the metadata for example to show required fields, but I am not using the full blown rendering of dynamic data.  You can pull the metadata like this:

```
public static MetaColumn GetColumn(Type t, string columnName)
{
  MetaModel model = new MetaModel();
  MetaTable table = model.GetTable(t);
  MetaColumn column = table.GetColumn(columnName);
  return column;
}

public static string GetDisplayName(Type t, string columnName)
{
  MetaColumn column = GetColumn(t, columnName);
  return column.DisplayName;
}
```

For now I'm just using some of the metadata.  Would like to know if you come up with anything further that this.

Comment: Thanks, we are delving pretty deep into this thing and hope to have a solution. We are using that MVC app against the latest bits (well, Beta) and things are going well enough. Will let you know if I can remember to do so!!! Thank you for responding!